# Specific recurrence in $2$ variables

Tags: recurrence-relations

I have the following relation:

$$F(x, y) = F(x, y - 1) + F(x - 1, y - 1)$$

and the initial conditions: $F(x, 1) = 1$ and $F(1, y) = y$.

How can I solve this recurrence?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You should so your attempts first.See this :https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question and this : https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/how-to-ask-a-homework-question

Comment: You should calculate a table of values. Try to find patterns within the table or perhaps you will recognize the numbers you are seeing. Hint: This is actually a fairly well-known recurrence, unless I am gravely mistaken.

Comment: Something fishy here. $F(0,2)=F(0,1)+F(-1,1)=2$ and $F(1,2)=F(1,1)+F(0,1)=2$ so $F(1,3)=F(1,2)+F(0,2)=4$ but $F(1,3)=3$ according to initial conditions.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Recursive_formula

Comment: @DanielV: Doesn't this require that $x>0$?

Answer (score 0):

I have programmed the recursive relation and obtained the result below, the blue lines indicating the "computation flow", for example on North-West corner: $46 = 9 + 37$.

You should be able, from this table, to elaborate conjectures (for example about powers of 2 that you can see on and below line with equation $y=x+1$).

[image]

Comment: For your next question, please, show a little what you have attempted...

Comment: Could you point out the flaw in my comment to the OP? Thanks.